# My secondary monitor turned "boxy" and won't change back

Tags: windows, windows-10, display, multiple-monitors, resolution

Picture of monitor:

[image]

Recently, I was playing a video game and the resolution to my secondary monitor became "boxy". About 80% of the width isn't being used and top 3% of the window is cut off.

Normally, this kind of issue resolves itself when the game is stopped or the computer restarts. No such luck. I tried to change the resolution of the monitor in the hopes that maybe it will reset itself. Nope.

The secondary monitor is a 19in monitor connected by a VGA cable. The primary monitor is a 32in TV connected by HDMI. The computer is running Windows 10.

My current resolution is 1360 X 768 which is the recommended resolution. Unfortunately, I don't know what it was prior to the change but I do believe this is what it was.

Comment: What resolution is listed (current-post-game) when you try to change it (back)?  What's the native resolution of the monitor?   Is the native resolution still listed (if not selected)?  Need a bit more to go on here...

Comment: A photo would be helpful...

Comment: Thanks for providing as much technical detail / specifications as you did.  It might also help to tell us the brand and model of the monitor and the graphics card, and maybe what Windows 10 release you are on.  Is the secondary monitor usable?  It might help if you could upload a photograph (don’t worry if you can’t). You say “Normally, this kind of issue resolves itself when the game is stopped or the computer restarts.”  Have you had this problem on this machine before? Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that will almost always fix it (may have more depending on response to comments) is to **uninstall the aftermarket/ISV graphics driver(s) for that card(s)**.  You usually need to **check the "remove driver software" option** as well, so it doesn't keep trying to re-install, before you're ready.
All this will move it back to the inbox driver, slow, clunky, but reliable.  It also more or less resets the display stack.
At this point (driver uninstalled), you want to reboot, and make sure your card is still using the inbox driver.
Once this is verified, reinstall the provided graphics card driver, and (in most cases) reboot.
That should do it, the native resolution would be set to default, in almost all scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I didn't realize that you could change each monitor's individual resolution by clicking on the monitor icons then changing the resolution. So when I was changing the resolution, it was only to the other monitor not to the problem monitor. Thank you everyone for your feedback though.